# Prove: $a^2\left ( \frac{b}{c}-1 \right )+b^2\left ( \frac{c}{a}-1 \right )+c^2\left ( \frac{a}{b}-1 \right ) \geq 0$.

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c$ are $3$ edge of a triangle.
Prove:  $a^2\left ( \frac{b}{c}-1 \right )+b^2\left ( \frac{c}{a}-1 \right )+c^2\left ( \frac{a}{b}-1 \right ) \geq 0$. Can it not do a brute force?

Comment: Brute force, while technically a valid form of proof in some cases, is not recommended when there are infinitely many possibilities.

Comment: I suspect this is some bizarre form of the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 2):

after simplifying we obtain $${a}^{3}{b}^{2}-{a}^{3}bc+{c}^{3}{a}^{2}-{b}^{3}ca-{c}^{3}ab+{b}^{3}{c}
^{2}
\geq 0$$
setting $$a=y+z,b=x+z,c=x+y$$ we get
$${x}^{5}+{x}^{4}z-2\,{x}^{3}{y}^{2}-2\,{x}^{2}{z}^{3}+x{y}^{4}+{y}^{5}-
2\,{y}^{3}{z}^{2}+y{z}^{4}+{z}^{5}
\geq 0$$ this is AM-GM since
$$x^5+xy^4 \geq 2\sqrt{x^6y^4}=2x^3y^2$$ etc

Answer (score 1):

The nice answer given by Dr. Sonnhard Graubner deserves a precision about the fact that POSITIVE values $x,y,z$ exist such that $a=y+z$, etc.

There are - at least - two explanations of this fact:

The first explanation uses the inversion of the linear system: the (inverse matrix) formulas giving $x,y,z$ in terms of $a,b,c$ are $x=(-a+b+c)/2, $ etc.  Thus the looked-for positivity is equivalent to the 3 triangle inequalities.

The 2nd explanation is geometrical: the points $I_A, I_B, I_C$ where the incircle with center $I$ of triangle $ABC$ is tangent to the edges divide these edges into line segments. Consider for example vertex $A$. Line segments $AI_B$ and $AI_C$ have the same length, $x$ (due to symmetry with respect to line $AI$). Thus, the lengths of sides $AB$ and $AC$ can be written $c=x+y$ and $b=x+z$ resp. for positive values $y$ and $z$. The third equation $a=y+z$ is obtained by reasoning in the same way with vertices $B$ and $C$.